# Where did SO and MSO chat's /favicon.ico file go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, 404-not-found, favicon

I was working on a userscript that uses `<canvas>` to manipulate the icons of various Stack Exchange chat sites. Because of [security restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2390232/313758), I can't use the normal version from the sstatic server, so instead I considered the fact that older versions of IE will always look for the favicon in the `/favicon.ico` location.

I tried https://chat.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico. To my surprise, I got a 404 file not found error. The same occurs for [MSO chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico), but not [SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico). It also works for https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico

I believe this to be a bug, not the fact that chat is dropping support for IE, since it actually works for the global SE chatroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite rules have now been rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

I thought all images were stored on sstatic anyway? (Apart from flair images by the looks of it)

This appears to be some kind of redirect issue.

Browsing to `http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico` should redirect to `http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/favicon.ico`  Unfortunately it doesn't - it redirects to `http://sstatic.net/mso/favicon.ico`